# Calling gwt static method from parent of iframe

Tags: gwt, methods, frame

I'd like to know how to call a GWT static method from the parent of the iframe in which the gwt module is loaded.

As a simple example suppose I have the following gwt class:

```
public class Simple {
    public static void showWindow() {
        Window.alert("Hello from the iframe");
    }
}
```

I create an html host page called "iFrameHost.html" that can run the function above.  Then in an unrelated GWT module on a different page I call:

```
Frame iFrame = new Frame("iFrameHost.html");
RootPanel.get().add(iFrame);
```

How do I now call the `showWindow()` method from the parent page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on Gipsy King's answer:

Simple Class becomes:

```
public class Simple {
    public static void showWindow() {
        Window.alert("Hello from the iframe");
    }
    public static final native void setWindowFunction() /*-{
        $wnd.jsniShowWindow = this.@com.package.path.Simple::showWindow();
    }-*/;
}
```

Then to call the Simple class from the parent HTML page:
Set the IFrame id and use the following method:

```
 private native void callShowWindow() /*-{
       $doc.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.jsniShowWindow(); 
 }-*/;
```

You'll have to make certain that the iFrame page has called setWindowFunction() but after that you can call callShowWindow() from the parent html page.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling You should wrap your function reference with $entry(...)

Comment: @Malli Don't ask questions by editing old posts because probably no one will see your question. Create separate question which will contain link to this answer and ask why does it work in Firefox but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

in Simple class:

```
public static final native void setWindowFunction() /*-{
    $wnd.myFunction = this.@com.package.path.Simple::showWindow();
}-*/;
```

in the iframe, either in a Native JavaScript method or in pure JavaScript:

```
window.parent.myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's close but not exactly what I want to do.  I want to call the iFrame's method from the parent page, rather than the parent page's method from the iFrame.  I've updated my question to show how I've tried to use your code but unfortunately I'm pretty weak at javascript and can't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, I've adapted your answer.

  If you want to call the function from the parent page give the iframe an id and then call:
     $doc.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.myFunction();

Comment: @Richard Can you please writeup an answer that uses your final solution and then accept it?